# why doesn't my table record the value I passed to it in access

Tags: ms-access-2010

I am trying to pass a value from the field ReportID (which is a number field) on form 1 to the field ReportID on the form called Budget_fsub after I click a button to open that second form.  I've tried this code to pass the value to the second form, and it looks like it works but when I go to the table which holds the values for the second form, the value has not been recorded.  What am I doing wrong?

Form1 with button that opens form2:

```
Private Sub cmdEnterBudgetInfo_Click()

On Error GoTo Err_EnterBudgetInfo_Click

    Dim stDocName As String
    Dim stLinkCriteria As String

    stDocName = "Budget_fsub"
    DoCmd.OpenForm stDocName, , , , acFormAdd, , Me![ReportID]

Exit_cmdEnterBudgetInfo_Click

    Exit Sub

Err_EnterBudgetInfo_Click:

    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume Exit_cmdEnterBudgetInfo_Click

End Sub
```

And here's the code on the form Budget_fsub:

```
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)

Dim defaultID As Long

defaultID = CLng(Nz(Me.OpenArgs, 0))

If defaultID = 0 Or IsNull(Me.OpenArgs) Then

    Cancel = True
    Exit Sub
End If

Me.ReportID.DefaultValue = defaultID

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

So, here is a working solution. I assume you have bound form and ReportID textbox is bound to the column. Please note, I have never been fan of using macros to manipulate the data..

Here is code for your Form1:

```
Private Sub cmdEnterBudgetInfo_Click()
On Error GoTo Err_EnterBudgetInfo_Click

Dim stDocName As String
Dim stLinkCriteria As String

stDocName = "Budget_fsub"
'close the form first
DoCmd.Close acForm, stDocName, acSaveYes

DoCmd.OpenForm stDocName, , , , acFormAdd, , Me![ReportID]

Exit_cmdEnterBudgetInfo_Click:

    Exit Sub

Err_EnterBudgetInfo_Click:

    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume Exit_cmdEnterBudgetInfo_Click

End Sub
```

Here is code for your sub form (Budget_fsub):

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

'global variable
Dim repID As Long

'form load event
Private Sub Form_Load()

Me.ReportID.Value = repID

DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSave

End Sub


'form open event
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)

SetReportID

If repID = 0 Then
    Cancel = True
    Exit Sub
End If

End Sub


'function to set reportID from the openargs
Private Function SetReportID()

repID = CLng(Nz(Me.OpenArgs, 0))

End Function
```

Hope this helps.